# AdMob without Firebase, not resolving

Tags: android, firebase, admob

We were using AdMob with out Firebase, we don't need Firebase integration and we are just trying to ad below in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
}
```

It's not resolving the AdMob variables, we are stuck here. We tried all clean, make project steps. Someone faced this issue?

Comment: If you just need ads why don't you try this:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xx.x.x'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
        }
...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Have you tried  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`after dependencies.

If not., add and sync once. Hope this will help.

for more details. read this document.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Firebase, it's best to avoid using any of the Firebase gradle dependencies. Instead, use this one to import the Google Mobile Ads SDK by itself:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.0'
}
```

You'll need to make sure the Google Repository has been downloaded by your SDK manager. If it's not, don't worry -- Android Studio will prompt you.

If you're interested, we wrote a [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/importing-mobile-ads-sdk-with-firebase.html) about the different ways of importing the SDK, and what your app will get with each one.

Hope that helps!